# Format a phone number with PHP

Tags: php, formatting, phone-number

In the database i have a field in the customers table called customers_telephone.
i want the output the telephone number like this(555) 555-5555.
within this CMS (oscommerce) the output on invoice.php looks like this.

```
<td class="main"><?php echo $order->customer['telephone']; ?></td>
```

i found a code that may work:

```
<?php
function format_telephone($phone_number)
{
    $cleaned = preg_replace('/[^[:digit:]]/', '', $phone_number);
    preg_match('/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/', $cleaned, $matches);
    return "({$matches[1]}) {$matches[2]}-{$matches[3]}";
}
?>
<?php echo format_telephone($customer_phone); ?>
```

but i am confused where to place this and what variables to insert, i only need the format, only here and for US phones only.

Comment: That is a function. You call it like any other function: echo format_telephone($order->customer['telephone']);

Answer (score 2):

That's ok.

In Invoice.php file make sure you have this following block of code before you use it in the `<td`

```
<?php
function format_telephone($phone_number)
{
    $cleaned = preg_replace('/[^[:digit:]]/', '', $phone_number);
    preg_match('/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/', $cleaned, $matches);
    return "({$matches[1]}) {$matches[2]}-{$matches[3]}";
}
?>
```

So put his line of code above somewhere, then in this line of code make sure you have

```
<td class="main"><?php echo format_telephone($order->customer['telephone']); ?></td>
```

That's it. You need to have the function before you use it on the code. Let us know if you have additional issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression

```
$phone_numbers = array( 
    '555-555-5555',
    '5555425555',
    '555 555 5555',
    '1(519) 555-4444',
    '1 (519) 555-4422',
    '1-555-555-5555',
    '1-(555)-555-25555',
);
$regex = "/^(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$/i";
foreach( $phone_numbers as $number ) {
    echo $number . ': ' . ( preg_match( $regex, $number ) ? 'valid' : 'invalid' ) . '<br/>';
}


555-555-5555: valid
5555425555: valid
555 555 5555: valid
1(519) 555-4444: valid
1 (519) 555-4422: valid
1-555-555-5555: valid
1-(555)-555-5555: valid
1-(555)-555-25555: invalid
```

Comment: thank you so much that worked great!! i learned something today!!i did not get a chance to try the last regular expression yet,

Answer (score -1):

If you have code for a function, for example:

```
<?php
function hello($hi) {
return($hi);
}
echo(hello("hey"));
?>
```

This would echo 'hey'.

Anyway, now to the point: you would want to run the following to echo the phone number.

```
<td class="main"><?php echo format_telephone($order->customer['telephone']); ?></td>
```

Make sure that you add the function code before you try and call it!